# Search a pattern and delete the word with that pattern in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

How to remove a word with particular pattern/keyword in Vim?

For example, if I have a file like below:

```
BB[0]:L BB[0]:R BB[1]:L BB[1]:R BB[2]:L BB[2]:R BB[3]:L BB[3]:R BB[4]:L BB[4]:R BB[5]:L
```

I need to remove all words with keyword `:L`.

As output I need something like this:

```
BB[0]:R BB[1]:R BB[2]:R BB[3]:R BB[4]:R
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that either with a regular expression replacement or by recording a macro.

This regular expression matches `PATTERN`, surrounded by any number of non-whitespace characters (greedy). More accurate would be a sequence of non-word-boundary chars (`\B`), but as far as I know that doesn't exist in vim.

```
%s/\S*PATTERN\S*//g
```

The other option is to record a macro and delete that word:

```
/pattern (search pattern)
qq       (record macro into register q)
daw      (delete a word)
n        (goto next match)
q        (stop recording makro)
1000@q   (replay macro 1000 times)
```

You may also want to try `diw` or `daW` instead of `daw`. There are vim help topics available for each mnemonic (`:help diw`).

Comment: `\S` is a non-whitespace atom. e.g. `%s/\S\+:L//`. The trick would be remove leftover whitespace, `%s/\%(\s\S\+:L\|\S\+:L\s\)//`

Comment: @PeterRincker That would require a non-whitespace character before the pattern, doesn't it. The OP did not say how whitespace should be removed. The macro may be easier when it comes to removing additional whitespace.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, @Srikarthik Kadapa can achieve the task by using `:%s/\S*\:L/*\S//g`.

Comment: @RajKumarMishra: You mean, in his example? Your pattern doesn't work. `:` doesn't need escaping, there's a `/` too much, you mixed the order of `\S*`. @SrikarthikKadapa should just replace "PATTERN" in my command with ":L" or whatever his pattern is - or use the macro.

Comment: @steffen thanks for correcting me. I messed it up. `:%s/\S*:L\S*//g` should work.